# Installation of Opera Extension fails?

Tags: opera, opera-extension

I am trying to install self-built extension for Opera .
As Opera suggests :

1.One method is simply dragging .xml file to opera.And it gets installed in developer mode.
 Also it works pretty fine in my case.

But the second method:

2.Zip the folder and change name from .zip to .oex. Now drag it to Opera.

And it gets installed.This doesn't work.

I get the following popups

[image: get this popup]

And when I click OK.I get the following message.
[image]

Anyone can tell me what is the problem.

Still the First method works completely fine.    And the Extension is also working fine.

Comment: Is config.xml on the top level in the zipped folder? I believe it has to be.

Comment: i got a main folder inside which 3 folders.1) popup(inside which popup.css and popup.js reside),2) includes(inside which injected.js resides),3) icons(for images).And config.xml,popup.html,index.js and index.html are in main folder. Now could you tell what you mean by top level ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common mistake. You are currently zipping the folder when you must **zip the files inside the folder**.

> You need to make sure you zip up your extension so that the files and directories that comprise it are in the root of the zip, and not inside a folder. To ensure this, make sure that you zip up the files inside your extension directory, and not the directory itself. Subtle, but it makes all the difference. — [Hello world extension](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-extensions-hello-world/#packaging)

Comment: Thanks man.It was irritating me alot.Finally,I made it.Thanks for your help. :)